# Multilevel Audience Targeted Global Navigation SP2013

Tags: javascript, navigation, term-store, global-navigation

Has anyone set up Multilevel Audience Targeted Global Navigation SP2013?
If I use term set I am unable to set security otherwise cannot set multilevel?

Comment: no need for js.. look here
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75636/permissions-and-managed-metadata-in-navigation