# Term-Driven Pages with Friendly URLs not showing for user

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store

The user is added to the site but unable to see the term, but is able see the page by typing URL manually.

While searching I could not find much except this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75636/permissions-and-managed-metadata-in-navigation) that didn't tell me much. What work around are their for this issue?

I know if you give them contributor permissions they are able to see it. This is not ideal, because it means they see other things they aren't suppose to.

Comment: Try to give explicit permission to the page. Open page -> Ribbon (Page) -> Page Permissions

Comment: Wanna add that as an answer so I can mark it answered if it works?

Comment: Has the Term Set where the Friendly URLs are defined marked as 'Available for tagging'?

Comment: @Waldek Yes the term in question has been marked as Available for tagging. Should it be unchecked?

Comment: Look this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118329/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation-show-parent-term/118602

Comment: Thanks for refreshing this post Anon. Nice to see this post is relevant and can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Managed Navigation, menu items linked to pages with specific permissions set are automatically hidden from users without those permissions.

When using the Managed Navigation and modeling the site navigation with Terms, as long as the particular Navigation Term is linked to a page using the Term-Drive Page with Friendly URL option, the term will be displayed to users only if they have the necessary permissions to access the associated page.

[Source](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/wcm-tip-33-managed-navigation-security-trimmed-term-driven-pages/)

Hence make sure the user in question has correct permissions to the page. Or provide direct permission using

Open page -> Ribbon (Page) -> Page Permissions -> And add the user directly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I posted it as an answer based on op's request.

Comment: mybad, i didnot see that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Any workaround if it works will be a good answer for me or someone with the same problem. Just making it easier for other people in the future looking for this problem